Expanded with non-constant Text child
I'm trying to create DataTable with localized header. However Expanded does not take non-constant child.
String col1 = MainLocalizations.of(context)!.getText('col1').toString()!;
    Text txt = Text(
      col1,
      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    );

    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: txt, // PROBLEM
          ),
        )

Compilation fails with
lib/main.dart:85:20: Error: Not a constant expression.
            child: txt,
                   ^^^

I need a way to create localized DataTable layout. Please advise.

Remove the const keyword in the line columns: const <DataColumn>[.
If a parent of a Widget is const all its children are automatically const too.
Final working code:
String col1 = MainLocalizations.of(context)!.getText('col1').toString()!;
    Text txt = Text(
      col1,
      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    );

    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: txt, // PROBLEM
          ),
        )

Edit: the reason behind error and why the solution works:
You cannot use a non constant value inside cost Widgets. Here, the Text widget contains a non constant string(the variable ‘txt’) whose value is known only at runtime. Thus, it cannot be marked as const, and removing const would solve the error.

Great! I had copy-pasted this code from example and overlooked that detail. Thanks!

@Subash It's always good to explain the why when answering a question

@Thomas, I have edited my answer and explained the reason for error and how the solution fixes it.
